# Не происходит загрузка

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте! Компилирую (fasm) из данного кода бинарник и загружаю с него виртуальную машину (VMware), но на экране ничего нет. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
org 7C00h
use16  

jmp Beginning 
nop  

db 'bootsect'  
SectSize dw 00200h
ClustSize db 001h
ResSecs dw 00001h  
FatCnt db 002h
RootSiz dw 000E0h
TotSecs dw 00B40h
Media db 0F0h
FatSize dw 00009h
TrkSecs dw 00012h
HeadCnt dw 00002h
HidnSec dw 00000h

Beginning:
jmp Main_Program



times (512-2-($-7C00h)) db 0
db 055H,0AAH



include "C:\main.asm"
```

main.asm

```
Main_Program:

mov ax, cs
cli
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
sti

mov   ax, 3   
int   10h


mov   dx, 0
mov   ah, 2
mov   bh, 0
int   10h

mov  al, 'a'
mov  ah, 9 
mov  bx, 0Fh 
mov  cx, 1 
int  10h
```

Answer (score 0):

**Первое**. Первый фрагмент кода (загрузочный сектор, первичный загрузчик) должен загружать некий код с диска и передавать ему управление не по метке (адрес которой вычисляется на этапе компиляции), а напрямую, типа jmp 0000:0500H. У Вас же по сути сразу происходит передача управления, причем неизвестно куда.
**Второе**. С такого исходника компилятор даст выхлоп в формате bin, который надо будет как-то еще записать на виртуальный диск. Я бы посоветовал Вам использовать не VMware, а Bochs, ему бинарники можно подсовывать как образ диска.
**Третье**. Стоит разделить программу на три части: минималистичный первичный загрузчик (512 байт), который будет *только* загружать вторичный и передавать ему управление. Вторичный загрузчик - будет определять конфигурацию железа, загружать основную программу (используя режимы CHS или LBA, или работая напрямую с контроллером диска), переводить процессор в защищенный режим, и передавать управление ей.